# compile error: method or data member not found, highlights .range

Tags: compilation, range

Keep getting this error. I don't get it, nothing has changed and it was working. Highlights this.

```
Sheet2.Range("R" & count2) = sheet1.Range("L28")
```

Although I have noticed that `sheet1.Range("L28")` drops the uppercase s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind all sorted.
replaced `sheet1.Range("L28")` with `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("L28")